# Python docx: Use different highlight color than default WD_COLOR_INDEX

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

Is there any way to setup a different color than default color that is specified inside docx documentations [Font highlight color](http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/features/text/font-highlight-color.html)
Or how to use a hex value for highlight? Maybe something like this:

```
font.highlight_color = '#265f5d'
```

Comment: I set a custom color to a run using LibreOffice Writer, and python-docx returns None for that run's highlight_color. After some digging, seems to do with shading (see python-docx's issue #309), but I couldn't find how to get/set shading on a run; it might not have been implemented yet in the library.